# Search if a given sub-string is present in a string

Tags: c, string, substring

I am using this code to find if a substring is present in a string or not. But the result is `Present` even if the substring is not present in the string. Basically, I am getting `Present` as the only result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i, la, lb, j, f = 0, found = 0;
    char a[100], b[100];

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(a, 100, stdin);

    printf("Enter substring: ");
    fgets(b, 100, stdin);

    la = strlen(a);
    lb = strlen(b);

    for (i = 0;i < la - 2; i++) {
        if (a[i] == b[0]) {
            for (j = 0; j < lb - 2; j++) {
                f = 0;
                if (a[i + j] != b[j]) {
                    f = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (f == 0) {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found == 1) {
        printf("Present.");
    } else {
        printf("Not Present.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what did you see when you stepped through with your debugger

Comment: I assume `strstr()` is off limits?

Comment: Yes it's off limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first strip the trailing newlines from the strings entered by the user:

```
    a[strcspn(a, "\n")] = '\0';
    b[strcspn(b, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Then you can remove the `- 2` adjustments in your `for` loop tests, which are incorrect as you should only adjust by `1` anyway.

There is a problem with the `f` variable: you should set it to `0` **before** the nested loop and test it just after the nested `for` loop but inside the `if` body.

Another problem is you should iterate the outer loop only as long as `i <= la - lb`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char a[100], b[100];

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    if (!fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin))
        return 1;

    printf("Enter substring: ");
    if (!fgets(b, sizeof b, stdin))
        return 1;

    // compute the lengths without the trailing newlines.
    size_t la = strcspn(a, "\n");
    size_t lb = strcspn(b, "\n");
    int found = 0;

    if (lb == 0) {
        found = 1;
    } else {
        for (size_t i = 0; i + lb <= la; i++) {
            if (a[i] == b[0]) {
                int f = 0;
                for (size_t j = 1; j < lb; j++) {
                    if (a[i + j] != b[j]) {
                        f = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (f == 0) {
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (found == 1) {
        printf("Present.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Not Present.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If the standard string function `strcspn()` is off limits, you can compute `la` and `lb` this way:

```
    size_t la = 0, lb = 0;
    while (a[la] != '\n' && a[la] != '\0')
        la++;
    while (b[lb] != '\n' && b[lb] != '\0')
        lb++;
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine. But, is there a way to do it without stripping the trailing newlines.

Comment: @IhaAgrawal: yes, by reducing the lengths appropriately.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I saw when I stepped through with mu debugger. Walk through the code with string 1 = "mouse" and second string = "cat"

```
   for(i=0;i<la-2;i++)
   {
      if(a[i]==b[0]) {    // m == c?, no
         for(j=0;j<lb-2;j++) {
            f=0;
            if(a[i+j]!=b[j]) {
                f=1;
                break;
            }

          }

       }
      if(f==0) { // drop to here, f does == 0, so we are done, found == true
            found=1;
            break;
    }
```

Comment: It's working fine if both the strings are different. But, it still gives Not Present even if the strings are same.

Comment: @IhaAgrawal your question says that it always says 'present', which is what it does for me